# Integration of a Bessel function times a sine function times a polynomial

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, closed-form, bessel-functions

I have recently faced the following expression (while trying to compute the Fourier transform of a RKKY-like potential):

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} \text{d} r\;  J_0 (k r) \frac{\sin \left(\alpha \sqrt{1+r^2} \right) }{(1+r^2)^2} \; r = -\frac{1}{\alpha} \int_0^{\infty} \text{d} r\;  J_0 (k r) \frac{1}{(1+r^2)^{3/2}} \frac{\text{d}}{\text d r} \left[\cos \left( \alpha\sqrt{1+r^2} \right) \right]
\end{align}

Although I can solve it numerically, I would like to find a closed-form expression, if there is one.

I found some related questions here, such as,

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} \text{d}r\; J_0 \left( \alpha\sqrt{x^2 +z^2} \right) \, \cos \left(\beta x \right)  = \frac{\cos \left(z\sqrt{\alpha^2 -\beta^2} \right)}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 -\beta^2}}
\end{align}
but did not really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [reference](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/7/Volume%202.pdf), Table 8.2 , entry (7):

$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{\left(1+r^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}}J_0(kr)r \; dr = e^{-k}$$

and according to Table 8.2, entry (41):

$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin\left[\alpha\left(1+r^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}\right]}{\left(1+r^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}}J_0(kr)r \; dr = \dfrac{\cos\left[\left(\alpha^2-k^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}\right]}{\left(\alpha^2-k^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}}\Pi\left(\dfrac{k}{\alpha}-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$$

where

$$\Pi(t) = \begin{cases} 1 & -\frac{1}{2} < t< \frac{1}{2}\\ 0 & \mathrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Using the convolution property of the Hankel Transform, if the convolution exists

$$\begin{align*} \int_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{\left(1+r^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}}\dfrac{\sin\left[\alpha\left(1+r^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}\right]}{\left(1+r^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}}J_0(kr)r \; dr &= \dfrac{1}{2\pi}e^{-k}**\dfrac{\cos\left[\left(\alpha^2-k^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}\right]}{\left(\alpha^2-k^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}}\Pi\left(\dfrac{k}{\alpha}-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\\
\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{k\cos\theta+\sqrt{k^2\cos^2\theta-(k^2-\alpha^2)}} e^{-k'}\dfrac{\cos\left[\left(\alpha^2-\left[k^2+k'^2-2kk'\cos\theta\right]\right)^\frac{1}{2}\right]}{\left(\alpha^2-\left[k^2+k'^2-2kk'\cos\theta\right]\right)^\frac{1}{2}}k' \; dk' \; d\theta\\
\\
&\mathrm{or}\\
\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\alpha^-} e^{-\sqrt{k^2+k'^2-2kk'\cos\theta}}\dfrac{\cos\left[\left(\alpha^2-k'^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}\right]}{\left(\alpha^2-k'^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}}k' \; dk' \; d\theta\\
\end{align*}$$

Neither of which look possible to easily evaluate symbolically.  Although maybe one of them takes less effort to evaluate numerically than your original integral.

Comment: Hi Andy,

Thank you very much for your answer. Indeed, the last integral can be solved numerically in half the computational time than the original one. It is already some significant improvement! Thanks.
I have very small comments though (for future correspondence and to help others):

In your answer, the first integral should read
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+r^2)^{3/2}} J_0 (k r) r \,\text{d}r = e^{-k}
\end{align}
This corresponds to the entry 7 of Table 8.2.

Comment: Oh my.  I fixed that error.  I also added a comment about the existence of the convolution.  (I'm not sure if the convolution actually exists, given that the integrand approaches a pole at $\alpha$.)  So please check your numerical results generated by the convolution with your numerical results from the original integral.

Comment: They do give the same results. I guess the convolution does exist. 
I was also thinking about the fact that one could use the fact that 
\begin{align}
\frac{\cos \left( \alpha \sqrt{1+r^2} \right)}{\sqrt{1+r^2}} = -\frac{\partial^3 }{\partial^3 \alpha} \frac{\sin \left( \alpha \sqrt{1+r^2} \right)}{(1+r^2)^2} \, ,
\end{align}
Since the integral 
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \text{d}r \, r J_0 (kr) \frac{\cos \left(\alpha \sqrt{1+r^2} \right)}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}
\end{align}
is known, maybe there is some way out.

Comment: I think you are correct.  If you can meet the conditions required for Theorem 5 here: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jyang06/stat411/handouts/InterchangeDiffandIntegral.pdf for each partial derivative operation, then I think you may have your answer given entry (50) in Table 8.2 of the Integral Transforms Volume 2 document.  I'm an electrical engineer and not a mathematician, so I probably don't have a full understanding of the subtlties of dealing with the $\infty$ in this situation.